# Why does OSX Snow Leopard ship with GCC 4.2.1, and is it possible (advisable?) to upgrade?

Tags: xcode, macos, gcc

Maybe they have a good reason, but I'm struggling to understand why a new OS would still ship with such an old compiler that was originally released in 2007. Did Apple modify it heavily and so therefore it has some features that are required? Is it possible to just download 4.5.1 and use it with XCode?

Answer (score 4):

4.2.1 was the last gcc which was covered by version 2 of the GPL. Coincidence? I doubt it.

Comment: I see, I don't know much about the GPL versions. Can you summarize? I've tried reading them but I'm left even more confused. Does this mean that I would have to compile my own from latest source, and are there any known issues with doing so? And what will Apple do once c0x becomes "law"?